# Cartoon TV series about a boy and an alien (flying head) living in the boy's watches

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched these series as a kid on TV in Russia around 2000 year or even earlier.

The two main characters are a boy, who has some watch-like wristband, and an alien, who is a freely levitating head and can shrink himself to fit into the boy's watches. The alien, for some reason, always had to return inside the watches and live there.

Each episode, as I remember, was about this alien helping the boy to overcome some difficulties using alien technologies.

One episode I remember was the other way around: the alien needed the boy's help, so he made the boy enter the watches, whose interior turns out to be a whole universe (though almost empty).

The series themselves certainly weren't Russian, but I didn't know any foreign language at the time, so I can't say what was the original even if I could hear it beneath the translation.

The animation looked 1980-style.

A few years ago I managed to find on the Internet only a short video from the series, which I can't find anymore. Now all my searches only result in "Ben 10", which is not what I'm looking for: the boy wasn't a shapeshifter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Widget, the World Watcher* (1990)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0213377/):

> Widget is an alien that has come down from the sky to learn about humans with the aid of his sidekick, Brain. They explore the world and educate kids on health, safety, emotions and dangers.

---

Found with the Google query `cartoon alien "in * watch"  site:imdb.com/title` which returned [this review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw0679732/?ref_=tt_urv):

> Anybody that hasn't ever seen this, here's the scoop: This alien comes to earth dedicated to protect the planet. He's purple, he can morph,and can even talk to animals. His pals? **Two earth brothers and a overactive head and hands called MegaBrain that lives in a watch on Widget's wrist.**

Comment: Oh, he wasn't human...

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz well, after 20 years, I guess memory may classify "kinda humanoid" as "yup, human" :) enjoy the re-watch!